# 'no module named spacy' even though i just installed it

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spacy

I just installed spacy on my conda environment, but when it is failing to import. I tried both `pip install -U spacy` and `conda install -c conda-forge spacy`.
As seen in the image, when i run the code `python -m spacy info`  it detects spacy. Importing works in pycharm. Is this a jupyter problem?

[image]

Comment: Did you activate the environment? :D

Comment: Sometimes the Jupyter environment gets weird. Unfortunately the easiest thing seems to be a reinstall. Here's a similar recent case that may help you in troubleshooting. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7435#discussioncomment-491525

Comment: @polm23 I tried that too but it still won't work.

Comment: Maybe open a Discussion at the spaCy repo. It sounds like you just have environment issues though. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/categories/help-installation

Answer (score 0):

Go to Anaconda prompt and install spacy. It worked for me.